# Slim Framework v3 running on built-in php server

Tags: php, slim

I'm working on an application that uses Slim Framework v3 and I'm trying to use the built-in php server to test the code.
The problem is no matter what I try I still get the stock 404 error message.

I'm running the web server with this command:

```
php -S localhost:8080 src/routes/api.php
```

And this is my code in api.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type');

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$settings = [
    'settings' => [
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ],
];
$app = new Slim\App($settings);

// Dependency injection
$di_container = $app->getContainer();

$app->get('/help', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson(['test']);
});
```

When I change the /help route in api.php to simply / and then visit any route in the browser I can then see the results of that / route.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to start the php internal webserver from the routes directory: `cd src/routes` and `php -S localhost:8080 api.php`. Then open: `http://localhost:8080/help`

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You must rename the file `api.php` to `index.php`.

Then add: `$app->run();` to the last line in `index.php`.

Start the app in the src/routes directory: `php -S localhost:8080 index.php`.

Edit: A better place for all the public files would be `<project>/public/index.php`